# Стоит ли обрабатывать входную строку? Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel

Есть код, который обновляет имя пользователя

```
  $object = App\Object::find(1);

  $object->name = $_GET['name'];

  $object->save();
```

Скажите, стоит ли при использовании ORM обрабатывать $_GET['name'] (экранирование и т.д.) чтобы обезопасить приложение от инъекций  или Ларавель сделает все самостоятельно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для получения параметров запроса используйте класс `Illuminate\Http\Request`

Пример из документации:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Store a new user.
     *
     * @param  Request  $request
     * @return Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $name = $request->input('name');

        //
    }
}
```

[Документация Laravel HTTP Requests](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/requests)

Comment: Можно короче, `$request->name`

Comment: @Dmitry OnGamer скажите, пожалуйста, данным способом можно получать и Get и POST переменные?

Comment: @Eaunemo да. Можно еще через helper `request()->name`